# Is it possible to add @Builder and @AllArgsConstructor in static inner classes [Lombok]?

Tags: java, inner-classes, lombok, boilerplate

Basically, the question is if it is possible to add Lombok's *@Builder* and *@AllArgsConstructor* to static inner classes?

I tried and it didn't, does anyone knows how to do it, or if it's possible?

I used eclipse, Lombok version 1.18.4.

The code where this happened is confidential, hence I can only show you a little mask version.

```
error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: Map<String,B>,String,boolean
[ERROR] found: no arguments
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

A similar error appears for each static inner class, as well as the outer class.

Thanks

Comment: ...so what was the error you got when you couldn't get it to work?

Comment: Works for me: `class OuterClass {
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    static class StaticNestedClass {
        private final String string;
    }
}`

Comment: My outside class also has the *@Builder* and *@AllArgsConstructor*

Comment: That also works (with Lombok 1.18.4). Please add to your question the exact error message you get, the Lombok version you use and where the error occurs (in maven, gradle, Eclipse, IntelliJ,...).

Comment: There is still no error message or exact problem description in your question. Please add that. Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I tried to replicate with a simpler version and it worked, but the more complicated (more inner classes) version is still getting an error similar to the one I described above.

Comment: I tried with several inner classes nested up to depth 3, but everything works as expected. We're not getting further without actual code, so you have to boil down your code to a minimal (non-working) example so we can reproduce the error. Please add that to your question.