# Lombok annotations for inner static classes

Tags: java, junit, lombok

Before starting, when looking for an answer to this question I've looked at the following question which didn't answer mine:
* [Is it possible to add @Builder and @AllArgsConstructor in static inner classes [Lombok]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342982/is-it-possible-to-add-builder-and-allargsconstructor-in-static-inner-classes)

In my tests, I created an inner class that holds my test cases:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
static class TestData {
    private final String testCase;
    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;
    private final int value3;
}
```

Also in those tests, I have a list containing all of those test cases:

```
    private static final List<TestData> testData = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
            new TestData("test case 1", "value1", "value2", 1),
            new TestData("test case 2", "value2", "value2", 2),
            new TestData("test case 3", "value2", "value1", 3),
            new TestData("test case 4", "value2", "value2", 4),
    ));
```

However, when I'm compiling the code I'm getting the following error:

```
error: constructor TestData in class TestData cannot be applied to given types;
            new TestData("test case 1", "value1", "value2", 1),
            ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String,String,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

**EDIT**
Since it seems to be something that does not work on my project I'm attaching my complete example code that is failing:

```
public class Testing {

    private static final List<TestData> testData = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
            new TestData("test case 1", "value1", "value2", 1),
            new TestData("test case 2", "value2", "value2", 2),
            new TestData("test case 3", "value2", "value1", 3),
            new TestData("test case 4", "value2", "value2", 4)
    ));

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        for (final TestData data : testData) {
            System.out.println("***********************");
            System.out.println(data.getTestCase());
            System.out.println(data.getValue1());
            System.out.println(data.getValue2());
            System.out.println(data.getValue3());
        }
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class TestData {
        private final String testCase;
        private final String value1;
        private final String value2;
        private final int value3;
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
}
```

**EDIT2**
You can find the code example in the project that I'm running on my machine (and some of my colleges) in this GitHub repo:
https://github.com/yonatankarp/stackoverflow_lombok

Comment: That's pretty strange. Be assured that I use Lombok with nested classes a lot and there's no problem there. I guess, you should create a full project (including gradlew) at github or alike, so that someone can clone and try it themselves easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - added a link to the question

Comment: There seems to be a problem when using Lombok annotations in test code. I don't know if that's gradle specific, or linked to an IDE.

Comment: In my case adding public access specifier made it accessible. It seems that lombok @data annotation only works on public classes. But looking at the answer for Gradle it looks like it has something to do with Maven plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with your setup, but I could reproduce and solve your problem.

Note that you problem has nothing to do with nested(*) classes, Lombok AFAIK didn't run at all.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "4.0.1"
}

lombok {
        version = "1.18.10"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I removed all mentions of `lombok` and added and configured a plugin doing this right.

I have no clue what was wrong.

---

(*) `TestData` is "nested", but not "inner". No idea, why, but that's what Oracle says: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Interesting enough that seems to work - not sure why my current setup does not support it - but thanks for the help (and clarification about inner classes and nested classes)

Answer (score -1):

There is a IntelliJ configuration where you can enable annotation processing.

Preferences -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotation processing

Your code worked on my IntelliJ too as stated by Chetan Komakula.

Obs: I don't think you need a static field there, i think you could use a @BeforeAll or @BeforeEach method to initialise your testData array. but that's an improvement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `Enable annotation processing` is already marked and seems to work for the outer class - however for the inner class I'm getting the issue. also, I've installed the plugin for IntelliJ for Lombok